# How to validate date in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to add validation to dates in laravel 8. Actually, I am generating a salary for workers but If the salary is already created and the admin tries to create the salary between already created dates then I want to show him the message Please select different dates or something else.

Suppose the salary between 1-10-2022 to 1-15-2022 is already created then I don't want to create another salary between these dates.

I tried to do myself but no idea had come into my mind.

```
 public function createForHamal(Request $request)
    {
 $result = SalaryMaster::whereBetween//
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why does the title ask for a validation in Flutter, but the code you've shared looks like PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

The [whereBetween](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) method verifies that a column's value is between two values.
You can use the whereBetween as follow:

```
$startDate = '2021-06-01';
$endDate = '2021-06-30';

$result = SalaryMaster::whereBetween('created_at', [$startDate, $endDate])->get();
```